# Execution not returning from exec

Tags: c, exec, execvp

I call the execvp function like so:

```
 int return_status = execvp("./myprogram", argv + 2);
 printf("return status is %d", return_status);
```

./myprogram does run, but the printf statement never runs. Why might that be the case?

Comment: This is what exec does.

Comment: Remove `./myprogram` as a file (or make it non-executable) and you will see the message printed.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, if `execvp` succeeds, your process is now running `./myprogram`. It cannot return to the calling code because the calling code has been replaced.

The purpose of the `execvp` function is to *replace* the currently-executing code with that of the specified executable. It returns only if it fails. If you want two processes, you need to call `fork` first and have the child call `execvp`. You can also use functions like [system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) that do this for you.